# Windows, Git and Jenkins

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

I'm just starting to look at Jenkins CI on my Windows 7 machine.

I thought for a first test I would create a git repo on my localhost which is aliased to

http://tests.local/jenkins/local

I setup a job in Jenkins, selected Git under source code management and added http://tests.local/jenkins/local.git as the Repository URL

When the job runs it fails with the error

ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone http://tests.local/jenkins/local.git

Is this a git issue or a Jenkins issue and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is just a typing error, but you've called your alias `http://test.local/jenkins/local` and your URL as `http://tests.local/jenkins/local.git` - note test_ vs testS

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately it was just a typo on my part.

Comment: OK. One way to check if it's a jenkins or git issue would be to try to run the same commands as jenkins in a Git Bash command line. These should be in the jenkins logs, should be something like 'git clone -o origin [repo_url] [workspace_path]'.

Comment: Also check the notes on the git plugin's page (esp. under 'Gotchas'). https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Comment: Looking at the error log I get

Error performing command: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe clone --progress -o origin http://tests.local/jenkins/local.git C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Localhost test\workspace
Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe clone --progress -o origin http://tests.local/jenkins/local.git C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Localhost test\workspace" returned status code 128: Cloning into C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Localhost test\workspace...
fatal: http://tests.local/jenkins/local.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: Hmm. Is your repo set up as a bare repository? That is, does the directory `tests.local/jenkins/local.git` exist, or is it actually `tests.local/jenkins/local/.git`?

Comment: In htdocs\tests\jenkins\local there is just .git

I edited my jenkins job to point to http://tests.local/jenkins/local/.git but I still get the same error

Comment: Have you run `git update-server-info` in your repo as mentioned in the error? Apparently this is needed if you want to clone/fetch via http, and will create dirs like info/refs in your repo. http://schacon.github.com/git/git-update-server-info.html

Comment: I've just run the command and my latest build was a success.

Now I can move onto figuring out how to move the latest build to another folder, then another machine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run `git update-server-info` in your repo? This is needed if you want to clone/fetch via http. Run `git help update-server-info` or see online documentation [here](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-update-server-info.html) for more details.

Comment: (Promoted resolving comment to answer, to help others stumbling on this issue.)